# C++ Dynamic vs Stack Objects and How to Use Them

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've always done allocations dynamically on the heap; I've done a lot of Objective-C programming as well as plain C and since I'm usually dealing with large chunks of memory, heap objects are necessary to prevent a stack overflow.

I've recently been told that using dynamically allocated objects is discouraged in C++ and that stack objects should be used whenever possible. Why is this?

I guess the best way to illustrate this is by example:

```
Class *_obj1;
Class *_obj2;

void doThis(Class *obj) {}

void create() {
    Class *obj1 = new Class();
    Class obj2;

    doThis(obj1);
    doThis(&obj2);

    _obj1 = obj1;
    _obj2 = &obj2;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    create();

    _obj1->doSomething();
    _obj2->doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

This creates 2 objects, stores them in the pointers, then `main()` calls a method on each. The `Class` object creates a `char*` and stores the C string `"Hello!"` in it; the `~Class()` deallocator frees the memory. The `doSomething()` method prints out `"buff: %s"` using `printf()`. Simple enough. Now let's run it:

> Dealloc
> Buff: Hello!
> Buff: ¯ø_ˇ

Whoa, what happened? *C++ deallocated that `_obj2` even though we stored a pointer to it*; that's because it's on the stack and not the heap, and C++ has no retain count mechanism like Objective-C (I tried implementing one at one point; it worked perfectly but I didn't feel like adding it to everything as a superclass). So we have to jump through hoops to keep it around after the function returns.

Comment: This isn't a question; it's a rant, and one based on almost complete ignorance of C++ coding idioms (and possibly on a somewhat hazy grasp of memory management concepts even at the C level).

Comment: "...In C++, the designers chose to add the pointless complexity of stack objects as a temporary alternative to heap objects..." **Stack objects are most definitely not pointless.** They make the [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) possible, which is probably the most useful and the most powerful idiom in C++. It is a cornerstone of modern C++; without them you get what's basically "C with classes."

Comment: -1. This isn't a question, it's an ill-informed rant. If you want to know why C++ is designed the way it is, then ask "why is C++ designed the way it is". Saying "C++ ate my baby brother, why was it designed to do that?" isn't going to get you anything useful.

Comment: but if you really want to know, then this is why C++ has stack-allocation: `std::ofstream("file.txt") << "hello world";` -- that little snippet of code opens a file, prints to it, *and immediately closes it*. Doing the same without stack allocation would have 1) leaked memory, and 2) never closed the file.

Comment: @jalf: Which is basically RAII in action. Thanks for providing an example. :-)

Comment: @In: yeah, I just thought a small example would carry more weight than an acronym the OP has never heard before ;)

Comment: @jalf: A rather ill-named acronym at that. :-)

Comment: @jfm429: If you intend to use C++ seriously, I recommend that you pick up [a C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of ranting. There are reasons why stack objects exist in C++. Take advantage of them!

Comment: jfm429: __The way to learning is by asking, not by proudly presenting your ignorance as a pearl of wisdom.__ (And didn't I tell you to go bashing C++ in public, making a fool of yourself, [I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019775/5054081#5054081) you to _research existing questions_ to __learn__ why, in C++, the stack is preferable.)

Comment: @jfm429: just to be clear, if you ask a new, neutral, question about how to understand stack vs heap allocated objects in C++, and how to make use of both, then I'd be happy to write a detailed answer to help you out. Despite what you may think, the way it works in C++ is actually extremely simple and logical. You just need to look at it without expecting another language's behavior. But ask another question without the flaming and trolling, and you shall be enlightened ;)

Comment: @jalf: I'd agree, except that I'm sure such questions already exist. hence my advice for him to research them.

Comment: The reason I posed the question the way I did is because certain people here on Stack Overflow (with rather high "reputation" I might add) stated that everybody using heap objects was "stupid". So, if that's the way C++ programmers think, then I want to know why. And I'm looking for a clear example of how to easily (with 1 line of code if possible) convert a stack object to a heap object so it's not destroyed when the function exits, and vice versa.

Comment: Also, I've re-asked the question because I notice that some people have closed it. Obviously nobody so far has even thought of answering the actual question, so we'll give it another shot.

Comment: @jfm429: You need to stop taking what we say on SO personally. As jalf as mentioned, if your question wasn't so rantish in the first place there would be at least one person who would be more than happy to answer your question. Now, I am of course not talking about you as a person; I'm referring to this specific question. Realize that just about everyone on SO answers questions on their free time. Your question must demonstrate that it's worth our time. One of the best ways to do that is to not rant in your questions.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of objects, think of "simpler" types. Would you do this:

```
void create() {
    int *obj1 = new int();
    int obj2;

    _obj1 = obj1;
    _obj2 = &obj2;
}
```

Would you think this would work? Clearly not.
It's very simple. You can't pass out the pointer to an object allocated to the stack (and, as a rule of thumb, you shouldn't pass out the pointer to an object you have just allocated. If someone allocates an object he is responsable to free it)

Comment: +1 @xanatos: This example would be just as valid with plain old C: `malloc(sizeof(int))`.

Comment: I would add that this is one of the rare examples where a little knowledge of assembly would help very much the C/C++ programmer. In assembly it's self-evident that you can't point to the forward stack (where forward is relative, I mean the unallocated stack from your point of view), because it isn't "in use". The C language hides this. Higher level languages with closures make a mess of all this, often hiding that things that seems to be on the stack really are on the heap.

Comment: I've actually had extensive experience in SPARC assembly, so I know how the stack and heap work, and subsequently why using stack objects in the example above doesn't work. The issue is that I've been told (by some very high ranking members) that using vectors on the heap can corrupt it, and that using heap data structures is "stupid" so I want to know what the "right" way is. Because if it involves only stack objects then the data structures are always deallocated when the function exits which is ridiculous.

Comment: I have been a programmer for 20 years and more. If I tell you that donkeys fly, do you trust me? There is a nigerian prince, my friend... He has a very good proposition for you :-) Considering how heap and stack work, stack buffer overflow (a type of attack) will do "different" damage than heap buffer overflow. This is true. I don't know what is worse. You could check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Answer (score 1):

Heap objects per se are not wrong, failure to manage their lifetime is.

Stack objects have the property that their destructor will be called regardless of how the code leaves the function (exception, return value). Smart pointers exploit this to manage the lifetime of heap allocated objects (a happy medium?)

Comment: The original comments were "it is almost certainly wrong to use a dynamically allocated vector object", "If you've also done this elsewhere in your code, you very likely have messed up the heap", and "Nobody said using a dynamic vector will mess up the heap. However, everybody that doing [sic] so is stupid". Note all 3 comments are by the same person (a contradiction between 2 and 3). This person has a very high ranking, so I'm at least taking his suggestion that STL objects with new can somehow corrupt the heap somewhat seriously. The question is, if that's wrong, then what's right?

Answer (score 1):

A basic design principle of C++ is that you don't pay for what you don't use, so that C++ can be used to write highly optimized code. Stack allocation is more efficient, whatever your language.

Comment: But the question is not really C++ specific at all. The "problem" with managing things on the stack is common for all C-derived languages. And combined with a rant that C++ is too stupid.

Comment: The title says C++, the question says C++, and the tags include C++. The question is about C++ featuring the ability to locally allocate objects on the stack and deallocate them when the local scope ends.

Comment: C and Objective-C also has that ability for sure. That makes it pointless to complain that C++ is a sucky language.

Comment: Which is fine for temporary objects (though very minor at most times) but as I said, I've been repeatedly told by very high-ranking members that STL data structures on the heap can corrupt it. I want to know why, and what the right way is if that's the case.